# MATLAB function errors with no solution

Tags: matlab

Today in my Uni course I've got a problem and the proposed solution was this one (with slight modifications made by me). But it has more errors than my actual solution, what is wrong with it?

Here is the function:

```
function result = fc(t, T)
f0= 50;
T=1/f0;
omega0= 2*pi*f0;
step = T/100;
t= -T : step : 2*T;
result = zeros(1, length(t) );
for index_t =1: length(t);
if mod( t (index_t), T ) < T/2;
    result(index_t) = 1;
else
    result(index_t) = -1;
end
end


a0over2 = 1/T * integral(@(t)fc(t, T), 0, T);

N=10;
a=zeros(1, N);
 b=zeros(1, N);
for k=1:N
a(k) = 2/T* integral(@(t)fc(t, T) .*cos(k* omega0*t), 0,T);
b(k) = 2/T * integral(@(t)fc(t, T) .*sin(k* omega0*t), 0,T);
end
```

The errors I get are:

```
Undefined function or variable 'fc'.

Error in asdadad>@(t)fc(t,T)

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
            fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
        [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
    [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in asdadad (line 17)
a0over2 = 1/T * integral(@(t)fc(t, T), 0, T);
```

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Is this all saved in a single file? The problem, namely, is that `fc` seems to be undefined. It's a single error message (undefined function) with a stack trace through all the subroutines that get called, finally ending on line 17 of your code. Saving `fc.m` as a separate function and save everything else in a script (preferably with a more sensible name than `asdadad`) and it should run.

Comment: Did that and all I get now is : 
Undefined function or variable 'T'.

Error in asdadad (line 4)
a0over2 = 1/T * integral(@(t)fc(t, T), 0, T);

Comment: @CoderDisorder of course, because you explicitly require `T` outside your call to the integral. You need to define that to some value. Your integral runs over time, `t`, and requires a fixed period, `T`. Hence, you need to feed it some value.

Comment: I get the same amount of errors as I did before even after creating the different file for the function